# Add new link to customer account page

Tags: customer-account, page, link, magento-2.2.1

I tried to add new link in the customer account link sidebar with add code below in customer_account.xml with my custom module.

customer_account.xml :

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-owner-reset-employee-password">
     <arguments>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">reset/emppass</argument>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reset Employee Password</argument>
     </arguments>
  </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

It's all works and i can see new link there, but how can i add the page for it? So if customer click the link, the customer will send to the custom link page.

Comment: Is you question just about adding a custom page? In which page is above link is going to be shown?

Comment: Yes it is, it will be shown in customer account page, just like "My Orders" link in customer account sidebar, when customer clicked the link customer will send to My Orders page, and my custom page will show like that too.

Comment: You need a routes.xml to create the route to your page and then you need a custom controller. Did you add that link through layout file inside your theme or inside a custom module?

Comment: @ShawnAbramson I add the link inside my custome module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you have to create a module. Inside your module create `routes.xml` in location `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="reset" id="reset">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Create layout at location `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/reset_emppass_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
                 <container name="categories1"  htmlTag="div" htmlClass="categories">
                    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\YourAnyBlock" name="myblock" template="Vendor_Module::index/index.phtml"/>
                </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Next create a controller index and an action index at `app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Emppass/Index.php`

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Emppass;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Finally create a template at `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/index.phtml`

```
Hello this is my template. I can do anything inside this file.
```

Comment: It's 404 page not found, am i do something wrong?

Comment: Yes you are doing something wrong coz, it's working in mine.

Comment: What page are you redirected. Share your steps in question so that I can check.

Comment: I create the link to http://www.testmagento.com/reset/emppass/ like in my question, and when i clicked the link, it's 404 error.

Comment: I mean how show how you followed my steps.

Comment: Found it, the code `template="Vendor_Module::index/index.phtml"` should be `template="index.phtml"` in the layout, but my other question is, how can i made the custom page looklike in the customer account page?

Comment: Hello edwin if you want to ask this question you should ask different question.

Comment: If your problem is solved, I'd love if you accept the question. I'm always eager to help you.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, i'll create a new question for it then, thank you again.